# Can you remove a zero dimensional subspace from a cube and obtain a planar space?

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory

The question, which came up in a conversation with my advisor Ola Kwiatkowska, is pretty much in the title:

Let $Z\subseteq[0,1]^3$ be zero-dimensional. Is it possible for $[0,1]^3\setminus Z$ to be embeddable in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Just to be clear everyone is on the same page regarding definitions: “zero-dimensional” means “having a basis (for the topology on $Z$ induced by the Euclidean topology on $[0,1]^3$) consisting of clopen subsets”, and “embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^2$” means “homeomorphic to the induced topology on a certain subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$”, right? ❧ Also, the fact that you ask about embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ suggests that you know the answer for $\mathbb{R}$ (and perhaps for $[0,1]^2$ instead of $[0,1]^3$): if so, you should explain what it is, or what you know about this.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen yes, regarding the definitions. For the latter question since a metrizable space has dimension $n$ if and only if $X$ can be covered by $n+1$ subsets of dimension $0$, but not by $n$ subsets of dimension $0$, we know that $\dim([0,1]^3\setminus Z)\geq 2$, so that it cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R$. I do not know the answer when removing a zero-dimensional subset from $[0,1]^2$, this is also an interesting question, it's just that in context the three dimensional version was more natural

Comment: We can assume that $Z$ is an $F_\sigma$ set from Lavrentieff theorem.

Comment: Obviously $Z$ has to be dense in $\left[0,1\right]^3$. By the zero-dimensionality of $Z$ we can find nonempty open sets $U$ in the cube such that $U\subset\left[0.3,0.6\right]^3$ and $Z\cap \partial U = \emptyset$. Now we need for such $U$ to have the property that $\partial U$ is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^2$. As the 2-sphere is not embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I'll be very surprised if there is a nonemptry bounded open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\partial U$ is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is negative in any dimension $n\geq 2$.

**Theorem:**
$\mathbb R^n$ can not be covered by a zero-dimensional set and a set homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$.

**Proof:**
Suppose for contradiction that $\mathbb R^n=A\cup B$ where A is zero-dimensional and $i:B\to\mathbb R^{n-1}$ is an embedding. Let $I$ be the interior of $i(B)$ in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ and let $R=i(B)\setminus I$.
Then $R$ has empty interior in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ and thus it is known to be of dimension at most $n-2$. Also $\mathbb R^n=A\cup i^{-1}(I)\cup i^{-1}(R)$.
However, $I$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$, hence its homeomorphic image $i^{-1}(I)$ is not dense in $\mathbb R^n$.
Consequently $A\cup i^{-1}(R)$ is the union of a zero-dimensional space and at most $(n-2)$-dimensional space and covers a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, which is a contradiction.